# Arduino tonecontrol circuit

Tags: arduino

Hi can we make a tone control circuit on Arduino using LM386 and if not then which other IC is used could somebody please help me out?

Comment: Are you looking for a passive or active tone control?

Comment: An Arduino is digital. An LM386 is analogue. Do you understand what you are trying to do? Please fix your question and explain. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: What part do you expect the Arduino to play in your audio circuit?

Comment: If your using the Arduino as a digital signal filter, you have much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Tone control circuit in audio system is a variable filter. It's used to boost some frequencies, to attenuate some other frequencies and let the others be as is. The purposes of such filtering:

- creative sound modifying (=adjustments for subjectively good result)
- compensating the uneven frequency response of the equipment and the room, often based on mesurements

Today high quality complex filtering is possible in digital domain. The signals are AD-converted and filtering is made as calculations. Arduino unfortunately is too slow and has too low resolution AD conversion for any serious real time digital audio signal processing. If you search for "DSP Arduino", the audio examples at their best are like the music or other sounds were played through an old-fashioned analog long distance phone line.

Thus Arduino as digital audio signal processor isn't a serious option - except if you have the signal already stored as digital data and you allow at 10...100 times longer processing time than the duration of the signal. But in that case you as well could use PC and Excel or Matlab.

If you still want to use Arduino as tone control, you must have external filtering circuit which gets control signals from Arduino. Arduino can have the following roles:

- remembering the right settings for different scenes and recalling them when wanted
- interface between the filter and the user
- automatic sound adjuster, does measurements and the needed adjustments (=not at all trivial task, the definition what is wanted could fill whole books even in natural language, implemented as computer software in only for  very limited and exactly defineable tasks such as find even frequency response or keep the volumes balanced)

PWM outputs (level shifted and filtered) can be used as control voltages for VCA based filtering circuits. Voltage Controlled Amplifiers (VCAs) are available as ICs. An example: http://www.coolaudio.com/docs/COOLAUDIO_V2162_DATASHEET.pdf

Whole audio manipulating equipment blocks are sold for modular system builders. Many of them use voltage controls.

For on-off switching arduino can output normal digital bits which can control analog switches.

Finally Arduino can be a servo system controller who rotates or slides motorized potentiometers.

For input data Arduino can read anything digitally readable (switches, keyboards, encoders, serial data) and even analog voltages.

Quite complex area, I would say. Sorry for only scratching it!

Comment: Thnx so much for the explanation actually I have to make an audio amplifier on arduino with vol bass and treble control ( which I learned were called tone control?) Thats what I was trying to ask  could u guide me plz and thnx again for taking the time to answer this